# Issue in Get argument property inside the Payload Factory

Tags: java, rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to call a request from JSON client to an DSS server via ESB,I am trying to call a fetch data service,The client Code,ESB Insequence configuration are given below.I am getting an server error as given below:

> LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:da913ea8-4122-4f58-9732-4106a55b465a, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unexpected error sending message back, Envelope:

The client code is :

```
 URL url = new URL("http://xxx:xx:xx:xxx/entitytype");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String studentDetails = "{\"hierarchyEntityRequest\":{\"entityName\":\"Chandragiri\",\"parentEntity\":900000001}}";

    System.setProperty("studentDetails",studentDetails);
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(studentDetails.getBytes());
    os.flush();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));


    conn.disconnect();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

The ESB Configuration service is:

```
           <payloadFactory>
  <format>
     <p:getEntityById xmlns:p="http://com.pcs.entity">
           <xs:data xmlns:xs="http://com.pcs.entity">get-property('uri.var.myhierachy')</xs:data>
        </p:getEntityById>
     </format>
     <args>
        <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('uri.var.myhierachy')"/>
     </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <enrich>
     <source clone="true" type="body"/>
     <target action="replace" type="property" property="myhierachy"/>
  </enrich>
<enrich>
     <source clone="true" type="body"/>
     <target action="replace" type="property" property="myhierachy"/>
  </enrich>
  <send>
     <endpoint key="HierarchyService"/>
  </send>
  <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
  <log level="full" category="TRACE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the message to the DSS server and do not a response back, you can specify the "OUT_ONLY" property to "true" as mentioned below.

```
<property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
```

If you want to get a response back to your client, you can include  mediator as the last element of your configuration or within the out sequence.

```
<send/>
```